# Can I setup recurring payments for a sass I'm developing via google pay?

Tags: credit-card, payment-processing, recurring-billing, google-pay

Is there an option to setup that users should be able to setup to make a recurring monthly payment for my software as a service using Google pay?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible although it may depend on the payment processor.

See the following providers and their documentation on the topic:

- [Adyen](https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/google-pay/android-component#recurring-payments)
- [Braintree](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/payment-methods/google-pay#recurring-billing-and-vaulting)
- [Stripe](https://stripe.com/payments/payment-methods-guide#google-pay)

You may need to check with your payment processor about their support for recurring payments with Google Pay.